# Rails 4 + Pundit : join model authorization in has_many :through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, authorization, has-many-through, pundit

In my Rails app, there are 3 models, defined by a `has_many :through` association:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations
  has_many :calendars, through: :administrations
end

class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations
  has_many :users, through: :administrations
end

class Administration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :calendar
end
```

The join `Administration` model has a `role` attribute, that we use to define the role — Owner, Editor or Viewer — of a given `user` for a given `calendar`.

Indeed, in the app, a user can be Owner of a calendar, and Viewer of another calendar for instance.

I implemented authentication with Devise.

I have also started implementing authorization with Pundit: authorization is currently working for `calendars`, where `users` can perform different actions depending on their `roles`.

**UPDATE**: here is the current `CalendarPolicy`:

```
class CalendarPolicy < ApplicationPolicy

  attr_reader :user, :calendar

  def initialize(user, calendar)
    @user = user
    @calendar = calendar
  end

  def index?
    user.owner?(calendar) || user.editor?(calendar) || user.viewer?(calendar)
  end

  def create?
    true
  end

  def show?
    user.owner?(calendar) || user.editor?(calendar) || user.viewer?(calendar)
  end

  def update?
    user.owner?(calendar) || user.editor?(calendar)
  end

  def edit?
    user.owner?(calendar) || user.editor?(calendar)
  end

  def destroy?
    user.owner?(calendar)
  end

end
```

Now, I would like to implement a Pundit policy for the Administration model, as follows:

- If a user is Owner of a calendar, then he can perform `Index`, `Show`, `Create`, `New`, `Edit`, `Update` and `Destroy` actions on the Administrations of this calendar.
- But, if a user is Editor or viewer of a calendar, then he can only do two things: 1. perform `Index` action to see all the users of a calendar and 2. perform `Destroy` action on his own Administration to "leave the calendar".

My problem is the following:

- An Administration instance only exist as the connection between a `user` and a `calendar`, as explained above.
- So, to perform actions on an Administration instance, I need three pieces of context: `administration_id`, `user_id` and `calendar_id`.
- However, Pundit only accepts two pieces of context in a policy, generally the `user` and the actual `record` (which would be administration here).

On the GitHub page of Pundit, in the [Additional context](https://github.com/elabs/pundit#additional-context) section, we can read the following:

> Additional context
>
> Pundit strongly encourages you to model your application in such a way
>   that the only context you need for authorization is a user object and
>   a domain model that you want to check authorization for. If you find
>   yourself needing more context than that, consider whether you are
>   authorizing the right domain model, maybe another domain model (or a
>   wrapper around multiple domain models) can provide the context you
>   need.
>
> Pundit does not allow you to pass additional arguments to policies for
>   precisely this reason.
>
> However, in very rare cases, you might need to authorize based on more
>   context than just the currently authenticated user. Suppose for
>   example that authorization is dependent on IP address in addition to
>   the authenticated user. In that case, one option is to create a
>   special class which wraps up both user and IP and passes it to the
>   policy.

Does a `has_many :through` association constitute one of the "very rare cases" mentioned above or is there a simpler way to implement authorization for my `Administration` join model?

Comment: I don't think `Administration` is required here. I think you can get `administration_id` from `User` and `Calendar`. Isn't it allowed to make queries inside Pundit's policy?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Sorry if this question sounds dumb, I am not very familiar with Pundit: how can `Administration` be not required in its own `AdminstrationPolicy`? Can we initialize the `AdminstrationPolicy` with only `User` and `Calendar`?

Comment: Should I implement these authorization rules in the `CalendarPolicy` instead of the `AdministrationPolicy`?

Comment: In `CalendarPolicy` can't you get `Administration` as `Administration.where(calendar:calendar, user:user).first`?

Comment: isn't `CalendarPolicy` already implemented?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in the question, `CalendarPolicy` is already implemented and working. Now, the challenge is to implement a different layer of rules for Administration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89419/discussion-between-dimakura-and-thibaud-clement).

Comment: To answer your previous comment, I don't know — ie I am not sure — if we can get `Administration` as `Administration.where(calendar:calendar, user:user).first` since this would call for User and Calendar. And the entire problem here is whether or not we can call for more than two parameters in a Pundit policy.

Comment: Actually we can. It's plain Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think, that this is an exceptional case.
What's the reason to break good practices, so explicitly stated in the link you provided?

You can just add `add_viewer`, `add_editor`, `remove_viewer`, `remove_editor` actions in your CalendarController.

First two can be authorized with your old `CalendarPolicy`.

```
class CalendarPolicy
  # old staff here

  def add_viewer?
    user.is_owner?(calendar)
  end

  def add_editor?
    user.is_owner?(calendar)
  end
end
```

For remove operations you will need `AdministrationPolicy` though (I was wrong, saying Calendar policy is enogh):

```
class AdministrationPolicy
  attr_reader :user, :authorization

  def remove_viwer?
    authorization.viewer? and authorization.user == user
  end

  def remove_editor?
    authorization.editor? and authorization.user == user
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The thing is that I have already implemented a `CalendarPolicy` defining rules for how users can / cannot perform actions on calendars: for instance, the Owner of a calendar can change the `name` of the calendar, but the Editor(s) and the Viewer(s) cannot. Now, I have another layer of permissions for users regarding the `roles`, as explained in the question. Should this other layer be implemented in the `CalendarPolicy` too, or in a separate `AdministrationPolicy`? Sorry if this does not sound clear, I am really confused.

Comment: It should be done in the same Policy. Otherwise you should use two policies for single calendar instance in your views and controllers. Right?

Comment: Add new layer as a new method in `CalendarPolicy`. It's a plain Ruby class after all.

Comment: And use testing to be sure your security is not broken.

Comment: Hmm but what if you want to display data about your authorization level in the view? The data should flow from controller to policy and from controller to view. Im not sure which way is right, I agree the docs point to this as being the correct answer.

Comment: Would it helped if I added my current `CalendarPolicy` to the question? This way we would have something concrete to discuss and think about whether we should include both policies in the same file or not.

Comment: @ThibaudClement great, please provide it

Comment: Done, I updated the question with the content of calendar_policy.rb.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is one of those rare cases.

```
# calendar controller show
@calendar = something    
@administration = @calendar.administration_of_current_user
authorize CalendarAdministrationContext

# pundit CalendarAdministrationContext
def initialize(user, administration, calendar)
  @user = user
  @administration = administration
  @calendar = calendar
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If this is one of those rare cases, doesn't it mean that I need to create something like `AdministrationContext`, just like the `UserContext` example on the Pundit page?

Comment: It really depends on how you plan on using the policy. But my thought are that the administration policy will always be used in conjunction with an @administration object and a stand alone policy for administration without an administration object would be useless?

Comment: Yes, this is a valid point. What I am trying to accomplish here is to implement authorization regarding how users manage roles: 1. the roles of the users of a their own calendars and 2. their own role in any calendar, disregarding their role. Should this be done in the Administration poilcy (since the role column is in the administration table) or should we do it in the Calendar policy instead? I am kind of lost here.

Comment: Strongly disagree. I think that "exceptional" case is only when you cannot get required information from given model. In this case you can easily navigate from `Calendar` to `Administration` models (using `User`). Using `AdministrationPolicy` will make it hard to use pundit in controllers and views.

Comment: Agree. On the other hand, you don't want to make additional queries in the policy if you already have that data in the controller though. You can do all the lookups in the policy at the cost of performance.

Comment: I don't think `Administration` model is needed in controller. The sole purpose of it is just checking permissions on given calendar. So I think it will end in one query in both cases.